# Invalid CSRF token if not using HTTPS

Tags: http, authentication, https, symfony5, php-7.4

I'm doing some tests with Symfony 5.4.x@dev in preparation for a new project.

I created a login form using `symfony console make:auth` and made a few changes to fix a few deprecated usages and add a `Remember Me` option.

Here's my `Authenticator` class:

```
class AppAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->get('_csrf_token')),
                new RememberMeBadge(),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_home'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

If I'm testing it under HTTPS (self-signed certificate), it works as expected, however, if I test it under HTTP (no certificate), login fails. Looking at the profiler i see that a csrf token was generated and gets sent with the email and password - however it fails to validate

POST Parameters:

```
_csrf_token: "870b3a5cfaf2bc0cf7cd2c75b5617.XKmjc7RWqjAgRmVbGaUNZ3FLJFSVhp1EjZZi_06oi8o.G5_PNvEi5XhTNVIrS_xJFkkEfnmtwMcMxaMxrjvS8oUS4ZIJxBXDXHcyXQ"
_remember_me : "on"
email: "me@domain.tld"
password :"mypassword"
```

Authenticator Response:

```
Authenticator failed.

[▼
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException {#344 ▼
    -token: null
    #message: "Invalid CSRF token."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/luis/Desktop/modularcms/vendor/symfony/security-http/EventListener/CsrfProtectionListener.php"
    #line: 51
  "authenticator" => "App\Security\AppAuthenticator"
]
```

Why would the authenticator work under `HTTPS` but fail under `HTTP`?

Comment: I just upgraded to Symfony 5.4 and my WebTestCase is failing with this message. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @winkbrace are you testing using firefox? I was using firefox on Ubuntu when I noticed this - then I installed a fresh Chromium instance and it wasn't giving me this error in it - but with no answers here I couldn't figure out the cause - maybe it was firefox not posting the csrf back in http for some reason I couldn't figure out - could you test different browsers and let me know?